# Struts 2 S2-016 Vulenerability Mitigation Till Upgrade

Tags: java, security, struts2, dmi

Recently Struts patched a vulnerability allowing attackers to execute remote code. Apparently not patching this is like giving black-hats a red carpet welcome with a bandwagon.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-016.html

Basically it allows attack command execution like this :

Legit action :

`http://host/struts2-showcase/employee/save.action?redirect:%25{3*4}`

Exploited action :

`http://host/struts2-showcase/employee/save.action?redirect:%25{(new+java.lang.ProcessBuilder(new+java.lang.String[]{'command','goes','here'})).start()}`

While I know that upgrading should be done ASAP, the as soon as possible will mean some time since our code base uses old struts versions and plugins.

Which will require some refactoring to upgrade the Struts 2 libraries, then those need to be tested etc.

My question therefore is whether anyone has any idea to stop this vulnerability from being executed? This will be only till we are able to upgrade.

I was wondering whether writing an interceptor to sanitize the URL before being evaluated against the OGNL is possible and if so will it mitigate this issue?

Other idea I had was to use the Java security manager somehow to stop arbitrary process invocations, is this possible? Will it patch the hole temporary?

The server being used is jBoss if anyone think that's relevant.

Comment: Do you have some server in front of your jBoss, apache maybe? How about restricting access to certain uri-s in it.

Comment: You mean something of a load balancer or a firewall with URL restriction capabilities?

Comment: That or a reverse proxy, like Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to `DefaultActionMapper` and how it handles special parameters. This class could be extended to override `handleSpecialParameters` method. However, if you turn off [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) these special parameters no longer work. Use the constant configuration

```
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are using DMI in at least 40% of our ajax calls... I'm going to explore the overriding option though....

Comment: Expose your own action mapper to the struts container, the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/actionmapper.html#ActionMapper-CustomActionMapper) on the Apache site perfectly described how to do that.

Comment: @Thihara: Creating custom `DefaultActionMapper` needs testing as well, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have some web server in front of your application server you can restrict access by url. In Apache there is [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module which you can use. Set `RewriteCond` directive `QUERY_STRING` variable to some query pattern and redirect to dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

As per the other comment, if you are using Apache in front of Tomcat, you can use this Apache configuration fragment to prevent requests reaching Tomcat:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} java.lang.ProcessBuilder
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```