# Mitigating CVE-2017-5638 Apache Struts2 vulnerability

Tags: apache, security, struts2

How do I mitigate the Struts 2 malicious `Content-Type` attack *without* updating my Java code?

Attack details [S2-045](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/S2-045).

Comment: Related: [Struts 2 S2-016 Vulenerability Mitigation Till Upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17984864/1700321)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the '%', '}', and '{' characters to the condition as well as they are also not valid Content-type header entries and are present in the POC exploit payload for this vulnerability.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-type} [$\#()%}{]
RewriteRule . [F,L]
```

Sorry if I got the syntax wrong as I have not tested this entry yet.

P.S.  I would even venture to add the '@', '?' and ';' characters, but those may break an application if filtered as I think they are actually technically allowed, but I have never seen those in a content-type header in any of our application implementations.

Comment: True - adding {} really helps. Adding ' and " would be even better.  Which gives us 

`RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-type} [$\#()%}{'"]`

Comment: It is a viable solution, but don't forget about html entities.

Comment: Point.  Also, it's always more difficult to validate input using a black list.  A more robust solution would be to develop a white list regex based on the RFC definition of the Content-type header.  But this would work in a jiffy.  https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html

Answer (score 0):

Apache's mod_rewrite can filter out the bad content type.

More advanced checks can be made - but this checks for characters we don't expect to see in the incoming content-type header:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-type} [$\#()]
RewriteRule . [F,L]
```

Comment: It is OGNL not EL, so `%` not `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this one to your httpd.conf or inside your virtualhost, after you've enabled mod_rewrite:

```
# MITIGATE CVE-2017-5638
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-type} [$\#()%}{'"] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Disposition} [$\#()%}{'"] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Length} [$\#()%}{'"]
RewriteRule . "-" [F,L]
```